# Clang precompiled headers - working with different /usr/include timestamps - perhaps by editing metadata?

Tags: c++, clang++, precompiled-headers

I've been trying to address a compile time problem. The infrastructure in question compiles multiple objects each of which uses a multitude of stdlib/boost. I've essentially hit a limit where simplifying the dependency tree is no longer worth the effort.

So, I tried precompiled headers - and it worked a treat! The problem I have now is fitting it in a large compute farm and CI. Specifically, not all machines were setup at the same time so the timestamp for /usr/include/ is often different.

The flow we would like to have is:

1. build certain shared libraries first
2. precompile header
3. Launch multiple jobs on different machines using shared libraries (fine) and precompiled header

The header is precompiled in the following way :

```
clang++ precompiled.hpp -o /<path>/precompiled.hpp.pch
```

When I use the precompiled header, depending on the timestamp of /usr/include/ on the given machine, i get the following metadata error :

> fatal error: file '/usr/include/math.h' has been modified since the
> precompiled header '//precompiled.hpp.pch' was built

It may sometimes be a different header too - eg assert.h is a common one.

So far I've tried the following:

- changing isysroot  & using glibc - exposed a variety of different problems (so a can of warms I'd rathern ot yet open)
- hack by copying /usr/include/ elsewhere and specifying that earlier in the search path. Unfortunately, doesn't work due to use of include_next in some headers but not others i.e. can't consistently force the headers to be picked from elsewhere and none from /usr/include

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

I am now even considering an even worse hack - trying to edit the metadata of the precompiled header. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any API to easily query/edit the PCH.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe [--relocatable-pch](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#relocatable-pch-files) flag would help?

Comment: I did try that - though didn't help the metadata check

Comment: As far as I know, pch knows only the sizes of headers it depends upon. The filedates are not recorded. Therefore if may be enough to reset the filetimes on all headers in /usr/include and other immutable locations.

Answer (score 0):

Have now managed to come to a solution (probably beneficial longterm anyway in terms of stability even if ignoring precompiled headers).

- Specify --no-standard-includes -nostdinc++ -nostdlibinc. This will ensure that the path is include path is stripped of includes due to the way gcc/clang was built. May also specify CPATH= and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=.
- Reconstruct path using a central location via CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH. This will mean the headers from /usr/include always come from a central locations and the metacheck will pass. It should also help stability of builds
- Link against correct version of stdlib